# It takes two tries to break my while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, tryparse

I'm doing a Udemy course and trying to complete an exercise where I'm asking the user to enter a number, or break the loop if I write "quit". After looping I have to sum all the numbers.

I almost got it working, but I have to write "quit" **two times** for it to break and I don't understand why. Appreciate any help

```
int[] total = new int[10];
int number;
int counter = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Write up to 10 number or 'quit' to exit early");
while (counter < 10)
{
    bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
    if (success == true)
    {
        total[counter] = number;
        counter++;
    } else if (Console.ReadLine() == "quit")
    {
        break;
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input.");
    }
}
int sum = total.Sum();
Console.WriteLine("The sum is {0}", sum);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each instance of `Console.ReadLine()` will read *a different line*. You should read the value once at the top of the loop.

At the moment your code does this:

1. Read line (request user input).
2. Can it be parsed to int? No.
3. Read line (request user input *again*)
4. Is it equal to "quit"? Yes.
5. Break

You should read the line once per iteration of the loop:

```
while (counter < 10)
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    bool success = int.TryParse(line, out number);
    if (success == true)
    {
        total[counter] = number;
        counter++;
    }
    else if (line == "quit")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input.");
    }
}
```

This will now request user input *once* and store the result in `line`. You can then perform whatever checks you need on this value before iterating.